# set two fields as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I show following sql query.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTableNameHere
PRIMARY KEY(Item_Id, Purchase_Id)
```

What does it mean by `"PK_YourTableNameHere"`. Is it current primary key of the table?

Comment: It's the name of the constraint PK_somenamethatyouwant.  It could be the name of your table or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the primary key constraint is optional (see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)).
Call it what you like or omit it altogether - it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is a name that you assign to the PRIMARY KEY you are adding to the table.  In your example there is no current PRIMARY KEY (or, if there is, your command will fail).

The name can be any valid identifier you want.  The purpose of given the constraint a name is to make it easier to manipulate (primarily, to drop it) later.